# C# WPF Binding DataGrid to TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, tabcontrol

i´m a newbie in WPF and have a Problem with data-binding. I hope you can help me:

Here is my XAML- Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="2,0,-2,0">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Tag="{Binding Rid}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dg}"   />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So i have a TabControl with a binding to a ObservableCollection of Tabs. Each Tab has a TextBlock as Header and a DataGrid.

Binding:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            DataGridTemplateColumn xx = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                Header = new TextBlock() { Text = "Edit", Tag = "Edit" }
            };
            xx.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
            dg.Columns.Add(xx);




            OCTabs.Add(new OCTab() { Header = "test1", Rid = 1 , Dg = dg});
            OCTabs.Add(new OCTab() { Header = "test2", Rid = 2 , Dg = dg});
            OCTabs.Add(new OCTab() { Header = "test3", Rid = 3, Dg = dg });
            MainTabControl.DataContext = OCTabs;



        }
```

and here the Tab- Class:

```
public class OCTab : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _header;
        private int _rid;

        private DataGrid dg;

        public DataGrid Dg { get { return dg; } set { dg = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Dg"); } }

        public string Header { get { return _header; } set { _header = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Header"); } }
        public int Rid { get { return _rid; } set { _rid = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Rid"); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my problem:
everything works fine, except for the DataGrids from each Tab. The DataGrid is empty (no Columns,...) 
The Binding doesn´t work and i don´t know why...

**EDIT:**
so is it possible, that each Tabitem has it´s own datagrid?

Comment: `Dg` property should be another `ObservableCollection` of item that you want to display in your `DataGrid`, like `OCTabs` and `OCTab`. You should not operate on UI controls in your view model. You can either define columns in `ContentTemplate` or let `DataGrid` auto generate columns from view model

Comment: aah yes, you´re right! The itemsource must be an ObservableCollection! But is it possible, that each Tabitem has it´s own datagrid?

Comment: `ItemsSource` is of `IEnumerable` type so anything that implements that interface will do but `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface as well which informs UI about collection changes

Comment: ok, thx!  so is it possible, that each Tabitem has it´s own datagrid?